# How do i modify a particular parameter datatype in Stored Procedures?

Tags: sql-server

I have a Stored Procedure, see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqdvc.jpg) picture .
I want to modify Department parameter as nvarchar(30), where it is currently as nvarchar(10).

So how could I achieve this?
Thank you so much

Comment: `alter proc procname (...,paramname nvarchar(30),..) as ..`

Comment: It showing this error : Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure addHOD, Line 19 [Batch Start Line 5]
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @department nvarchar(30)
set @department =  CAST (@department_in as nvarchar(30))
```

Comment: what should be the full syntax ?

Comment: i don't know what your SPROC looks like... but in my previous code snippet,  @department_in (nvarchar(10)) must be initialized by select cursor from your table, and the cast provides the nvarchar(30)

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on it, you have the option 'modify' which will generate an alter procedure script for you.

Change the parameter to an nvarchar(30) and run the alter script.

Comment: Giving an error : Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure addHOD, Line 19 [Batch Start Line 5]
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the type of variable if you already dclared it. In other words:
to change the type of variable, yo need to declare it once again, and as [this thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96797/how-to-re-declare-t-sql-variables-if-it-already-exist) states, you cannot do it.

Comment: I am not changing its type, but i want to change its size

Comment: The answer still applies. I forgot to ask: do you want to change it during runtime? If so, then you can't do it, sorry. But if you want to do it once, @Carra answer is the one you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to query database objects according to their parameter names, types, length etc using the information schema view

```
[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[PARAMETERS]
```

But you cannot simply update the length on some tables to modify the length, etc of a procedure parameter.

All these objects should be updated using

```
ALTER PROCEDURE ...
```

command, at least for stored procedures

You can get the source codes of a procedure by running sp_helptext as follows

```
sp_helptext yourStoredProcedureName
```

Then modify the parameter and execute the script as ALTER command